# Python parsing string value in csv with Panda

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to Python and I am trying to read a csv file using pandas but I have a bit of a problem within my csv file.
I have strings which contains commas at the end and this creates an undesired column at towards the end as shown:

[image: table of csv file]

This is the raw csv:

[image: raw csv]

For example, on line `14`, the green string value ends with a comma and creates a new column which then gives me parsing errors when using this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 8, saw 7

Is there a way I can clean up this and *merge* the last two columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` to replace APP with the last column where APP is missing, then drop the last column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df['APP'] = np.where(df.app.isna(), df[-1], df.APP)
df = df.iloc[:,:-1]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem it would be helpful to explain what is going on here.

Comment: Ah! that makes sense. Thanks